# Alignment and sizing of stacked icons using fontawesome not working

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to use stacked icons with fontawesome.  I followed the example in Dave Gandy's excellent blog post.
http://blog.fontawesome.io/2014/05/19/stacking-text-and-icons/

Stacking works fine, but I am trying to align a stacked icon with a non-stacked icon (which is fa-5x).  I cannot seem to make the size/alignment of a stacked icon match the size/alignment of a non-stacked icon.
See this codepen: http://codepen.io/rfiol/pen/YPQNaG

```
<i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-5x"></i> 

<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <strong class="fa-stack-1x calendar-text">27</strong>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

CSS

```
.calendar-text { 
  margin-top: .3em;  
}
.calendar-text { 
  font-size:100%;
}
.col-md-1:nth-child(3) .calendar-text-half { 
  font-size:50%;
}
.col-md-1:nth-child(3) .fa-stack { 
  transform: scale(2,2);
}
.fa-stack {
  font-size:2.5em;
}
.row {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  display:block; 
}
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEwBNd